# Magento theme to inherit from more than 1 package

Tags: php, magento

Is it possible in magento to have a theme inherit from more than 1 other theme (aside from base)

The typical hierarchy is theme -> default -> base.

I would like the following:

theme -> theme2 -> default -> base

Is this possible? If not, can anyone offer any points of interest in the magento code base for me to investigate a possible solution.

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0):

The answer you seek is in the class `Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package`. In particular the `_fallback` method:

```
protected function _fallback($file, array &$params, array $fallbackScheme = array(array()))
{
    if ($this->_shouldFallback) {
        foreach ($fallbackScheme as $try) {
            $params = array_merge($params, $try);
            $filename = $this->validateFile($file, $params);
            if ($filename) {
                return $filename;
            }
        }
        $params['_package'] = self::BASE_PACKAGE;
        $params['_theme']   = self::DEFAULT_THEME;
    }
    return $this->_renderFilename($file, $params);
}
```

As you can see, it will loop through a list of fallback package/theme combinations until it finds one that contains the file it is looking for. If it doesn't find it, it will eventually end up using base/default.

Unfortunately, the data passed to `fallbackScheme` is hardcoded in the same class, as you can see by this call (though there is another method that does something similar, namely `getSkinUrl`):

```
public function getFilename($file, array $params)
{
    Varien_Profiler::start(__METHOD__);
    $this->updateParamDefaults($params);
    $result = $this->_fallback($file, $params, array(
        array(),
        array('_theme' => $this->getFallbackTheme()),
        array('_theme' => self::DEFAULT_THEME),
    ));
    Varien_Profiler::stop(__METHOD__);
    return $result;
}
```

For a typical request, with package `some_package` and theme `some_theme`, it will be something along these lines:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["_theme"]=>
    string(1) "some_theme"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["_theme"]=>
    string(7) "default"
  }
}
```

If you truly want multiple theme inheritance, you would need to rewrite the above two methods and add additional fallbacks.

Fortunately, themes will become modules in Magento2, which will solve this issue.